# How to restore the default signal processing behavior on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, signals

I have found the signal processing behavior on my Solaris 10 is changed. For example, when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the program can't exit. Use `psig` to check the signal processing behavior:

```
HUP     default
INT     ignored
QUIT    ignored
ILL     default
```

I can see the `INT` signal is changed to `ignored`. I want to restore the default behavior, How can I do it? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Which `process` is your `psig` output for? It's very possible that the program you're trying to exit is set up to ignore `SIGINT`.

Comment: @Harvinder: No, all the programs have ignored the SIGINT, so I think it is a system problem, and want to know how to restore it,

Comment: [`Resetting SIGINT and SIGTSTP`](http://superuser.com/a/674184) - the comments on that page provide some useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Running the command `trap - INT QUIT` from a shell should restore the default signal handling for that shell and the processes that it subsequently executes. You may want to add this to your `~/.profile`.

Check if some initialization file somewhere contains `trap "" INT QUIT` or something similar (which tells the shell to ignore the signal).

Comment: I have tried your method, but it doesn't work on Solaris.

Comment: To reset signals on Solaris's default shell, omit the `-` from the command: `trap INT QUIT`.